# Multicolored edittext hint

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint, textinputlayout

Is there a way to set multiple colors to the edittext's hint when wrapped by android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout without compromising the behaviour of floating edittexts?

like,
Headline*

Headline and * with different colored hint

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114113/different-colors-at-edittext-in-android) solution also works for hints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to set hint for TextInputLayout, not for Edittext. As i need floating animation for hint text.

Comment: Have you tried this using [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: Hey @RKS have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try this! If you want to use it for setText just add BufferType.SPANNABLE (see below)

```
    String redPart = "Hello";
    String bluePart = "World";

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    SpannableString redColoredString= new SpannableString(redPart);
    redColoredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, redPart.length(), 0);
    builder.append(redColoredString);

    SpannableString blueColoredString= new SpannableString(bluePart);
    blueColoredString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, bluePart.length(), 0);
    builder.append(blueColoredString);


    myEditText.setHint(builder)

    //do following for setText
    myEditText.setText(builder,BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SpannableString` class which allows you to use different styles on parts of your string ... If I remember correctly, `TextAppearanceSpan` class is used for coloring a text..

Answer (score 0):

See below code this is work for me.

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(textView);
 Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Hello world");

 wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 6, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

 editText.setHint(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: The hint doesn't float to the top if this method is applied. Any idea to overcome that?

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this by programtically

```
SpannableString spString = new SpannableString("HEADERLINE*");
    spString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.MAGENTA), 11,     spString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    metUserName.setHint(spString);
```