# Multicolored edittext hint in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputedittext

Is there a way to set multiple colors to the `EditText` hint when wrapped by `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` without compromising the behavior of floating `EditText Hint`?

** e.g:**
Headline*
'Headline' in black color and '*' in red

Literally, my question is an exact duplicate of this question: [Multicolored edittext hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40239555/9636037) .

I am posting it again because there is no valid answer to that question. (Please don't mark my question as a duplicate to that one !!)

I have tried the answer given there an this was the **outcome** :

[image]

You can see that the floating property of the `TextInputLayout` is no longer applicable. (Want hint to float like this)

[image]
Is there anyway to maintain the behaviour of the `TextInputLayout EditText` with multi-color hint?

***Code:***

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/appointment_patient_name_et_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

***Attempt to set multi-color hint :***

```
 appointment_patient_name_et = findViewById(R.id.appointment_patient_name_et_id);
 Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Hello world");
 wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 6, 
 Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 appointment_patient_name_et.setHint(wordtoSpan);
```

***Edit 1:***
After using git library suggested by ADM...

**.java :**

```
MaterialEditText appointment_patient_name_et;

appointment_patient_name_et = findViewById(R.id.appointment_patient_name_et_id);

//  Multicolor hint
final Spannable spannable1 = new SpannableString("Patient's Name *");
spannable1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)), 0,
                spannable1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannable1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                spannable1.length() - 1, spannable1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Spannable spannable2 = new SpannableString("Patient's Name *");
spannable2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)), 0,
                spannable2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannable2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                spannable2.length() - 1, spannable2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

appointment_patient_name_et.setHint(spannable1);
appointment_patient_name_et.setFloatingLabelText(spannable2);
appointment_patient_name_et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            appointment_patient_name_et.setFloatingLabelAlwaysShown(true);
            appointment_patient_name_et.setHint("");
        } else {    
            appointment_patient_name_et.setFloatingLabelAlwaysShown(false);
            appointment_patient_name_et.setHint(spannable1);
        }
    }
});
```

**.xml:**

```
<com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
    android:id="@+id/appointment_patient_name_et_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="Patient's Name *"
    app:met_baseColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:met_clearButton="true"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
    app:met_floatingLabelTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
    app:met_textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:met_textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

***Output :***
Without gaining focus :

[image]

After gaining focus :
[image]

Is there any way to make the asterisk in the floating hint in a different color than the floating hint color?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/textInput"        
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And set the span to `Edittext`.

```
TextInputLayout textInput = findViewById(R.id.textInput);
    Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Hello world");
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 6,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textInput.setHint(wordtoSpan);

    EditText et2=findViewById(R.id.et2);
    et2.setHint(wordtoSpan);
```

This will make Hint float-able. Hint will float with the color defined in style by default `colorAccent`. 
if you want to keep the color of Floated Hint as Spannable . Thats not so trivial i think.

If above answer does not work for you . Also i could not make work maybe it its quite trivial but i can not figure out right now.
As a Solution you can try https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText. I have tested it its working as needed i guess . try it like :

```
 <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
    android:id="@+id/et3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:met_textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:met_baseColor="@android:color/black"
    app:met_floatingLabel="highlight"
    app:met_maxCharacters="20"
    app:met_floatingLabelTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    app:met_primaryColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:met_singleLineEllipsis="true"
    />
```

And set the hint as :

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Hello world");
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, wordtoSpan.length(),
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 2, 6,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    MaterialEditText et3=findViewById(R.id.et3);
    et3.setFloatingLabelText(wordtoSpan);
    et3.setHint(wordtoSpan);
```

Comment: Changing this line : `EditText et2=findViewById(R.id.et2);` to `TextInputEditTextet2=findViewById(R.id.et2);` doesn't make the hint float (same as in the pic in my question)

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply... The updated answer seems to work partially. The hint color changed to different colors before gaining focus, but after gaining focus (when hint floats) the multi-color doesn't work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: For this you can try the 2nd part of answer . I think you have to make some customization to the floating edit text .

Comment: Have made an edit to my question. Please go through it! And thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: As i said previously AFAIK this is not possible without customization . Just go through the code of library and customize it . Maybe there is a easy way to do this but you have to check out the code anyway. See [here](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/blob/master/README.md) all features are are listed .

Comment: I had already gone through the available features and I couldn't find what I need...

Comment: I have already tried customizing and only after that I could make the hint floatable as soon as it gains focus. (By the library default, hint turns into floating mode only when first character is entered ).

Comment: @Abhi did any of the answers worked for you? can you post your answer?